# Why do I get unreadable strings when parsing site using lxml and python?

Tags: python, parsing, encoding, lxml

I'm trying to parse site with python and lxml. Also I'm using requests. This is part of my code.

```
result = session_requests.get(
    url, 
    headers = dict(referer = url)
)

tree = html.fromstring(result.content)
test = tree.xpath("//div[@class='db_day']/table/thead/tr/th[@class='mark']/text()")

print(test)
```

It returns me this result. [link to screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THT7p.png)

I think that it isn't normal. I'm trying to parse website with cyrillic symbols. But before, when I used the same code on the same website with cyrillic symbols, everything was fine.

Could you suggest a solution to this issue, please?

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: "But before… everything was fine."—what changed between "before" and now?

Comment: I changed the page that I parsed on the website.

Comment: Are unreadable symbols a common result for cyrillic characters in lxml?

Comment: You're passing bytes to `lxml.html.fromstring`, so it has to guess the correct encoding to use.  You might have better luck letting `requests` do the decoding, and passing 1result.text` to `lxml.html.fromstring`.

Comment: Thans, it worked for me!